# How to use DevExtreme DxMaps from scratch for desktop web development?

Tags: maps, devexpress, devextreme

I am supposed to use a map showing all specified locations marked in it. It needs be a general map showing all locations and routes along with the markers. However,
when i used dxMap in my web development project nothing showed up. The screen just remained blank.

below is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Map.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapContainer" style="height:450px;max-width:750px;margin:0px auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Separate .js file code is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('#mapContainer').dxMap({});
});
```

I have used this approach following the link :
http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Data_Visualization/Configure_VectorMap/?version=15_1#Create_a_Vector_Map

The link shows how to configure a DxVectorMap. But this approach doesn't seem to work for dxMap. Please can anyone guide what approach should i use for dxMap?

Comment: Maybe these demos will be helpful: [Map Markers](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/maps-map-markers), [Map Routes](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/maps-map-routes)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just solved the problem using the correct Cdns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code created a dxmap once the head tag was changed with correct CDNs (which included support for desktop web applications as well)

```
 <head>
    <title>Add a Widget - jQuery Approach</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
    **<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.1.7/js/dx.webappjs.js"></script>**
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.1.7/css/dx.common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.1.7/css/dx.light.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
```